# sort columns of a data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, col

**Possible duplicate:**  [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

I have a data frame in different orders (in terms of columns).

```
       ID_REF      VALUE       ABS_CALL           DETECTION.P.VALUE
1    10071_s_at 3473.60000        P/present       0.000219000
2       1053_at  643.20000        P/present       0.000673000
3        117_at  564.00000        M/Marginal      0.000322000
4     1255_g_at    9.40000        A/absent        0.602006000
5       1294_at  845.60000        P/present       0.000468000
6       1320_at   94.30000        A/absent        0.204022000
```

Now below the order of columns is changed

```
 VALUE      ID_REF     ABS_CALL           DETECTION P-VALUE
1  3473.6   10071_s_at  P/present          0.000219
2  643.2    1053_at     P/present          0.000673
3  564      117_at      M/marginal         0.000322
4  9.4      1255_g_at   A/absent           0.602006
5  845.6    1294_at     P/present          0.000468
6  94.3     1320_at     A/absent           0.204022
```

Again it is changed

```
   DETECTION P-VALUE    VALUE   ID_REF     ABS_CALL
1  0.000219             3473.6  10071_s_at  P
2  0.000673             643.2   1053_at     P
3  0.000322             564     117_at      M
4  0.602006             9.4     1255_g_at   A
5  0.000468             845.6   1294_at     P
6  0.204022             94.3    1320_at     A
```

Here I have the same data frame in different column orders. I don't know the order of the data frame, so I want to put the data in the below format:

```
      ID_REF      VALUE       ABS_CALL           DETECTION.P.VALUE
1    10071_s_at 3473.60000        P/present       0.000219000
2       1053_at  643.20000        P/present       0.000673000
3        117_at  564.00000        M/Marginal      0.000322000
4     1255_g_at    9.40000        A/absent        0.602006000
5       1294_at  845.60000        P/present       0.000468000
6       1320_at   94.30000        A/absent        0.204022000
```

Here i need to  check if there is a substring of `_at` in any column then put that as the first column. If any column has values greater than 1 then put that column as the second column of data frame. If any column has levels `P`,`A`,`M` or `present` ,`absent` ,`marginal` then put that as the third column and finally any column with values less than 1 will be the last. Can anybody please tell me how to do this in R efficiently?

Note: Column names are not permanent, those can be anything (different names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't elegant by any means, but you could write a function that looks at only a single row and search for each of your criteria:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,
text="ID_REF      VALUE       ABS_CALL           DETECTION.P.VALUE
1    10071_s_at 3473.60000        P/present       0.000219000
2       1053_at  643.20000        P/present       0.000673000
3        117_at  564.00000        M/Marginal      0.000322000
4     1255_g_at    9.40000        A/absent        0.602006000
5       1294_at  845.60000        P/present       0.000468000
6       1320_at   94.30000        A/absent        0.204022000")

dat2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,
text="VALUE      ID_REF     ABS_CALL           'DETECTION P-VALUE'
1  3473.6   10071_s_at  P/present          0.000219
2  643.2    1053_at     P/present          0.000673
3  564      117_at      M/marginal         0.000322
4  9.4      1255_g_at   A/absent           0.602006
5  845.6    1294_at     P/present          0.000468
6  94.3     1320_at     A/absent           0.204022")

dat3 <- read.table(header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,
text="   'DETECTION P-VALUE'    VALUE   ID_REF     ABS_CALL
1  0.000219             3473.6  10071_s_at  P
2  0.000673             643.2   1053_at     P
3  0.000322             564     117_at      M
4  0.602006             9.4     1255_g_at   A
5  0.000468             845.6   1294_at     P
6  0.204022             94.3    1320_at     A")


f <- function(data) {
  d1 <- data[1, , drop = FALSE]
  ## from row 1, separate out numerics, p-value is < 1
  ## and the other we assume is value
  nums <- d1[, nn <- sapply(d1, is.numeric)]
  p <- names(nums[, nums < 1, drop = FALSE])
  val <- setdiff(names(nums), p)

  ## take all the other columns, find `_at$` as id
  ## and assume the other column is `abs_call`
  ch <- d1[, !nn, drop = FALSE]
  id <- names(ch[, grepl('_at$', as.character(unlist(ch))), drop = FALSE])
  abs <- setdiff(names(ch), id)

  ## order by the name found
  data[, c(id, val, abs, p)]
}

lapply(list(dat1, dat2, dat2), f)

# [[1]]
#       ID_REF  VALUE   ABS_CALL DETECTION.P.VALUE
# 1 10071_s_at 3473.6  P/present          0.000219
# 2    1053_at  643.2  P/present          0.000673
# 3     117_at  564.0 M/Marginal          0.000322
# 4  1255_g_at    9.4   A/absent          0.602006
# 5    1294_at  845.6  P/present          0.000468
# 6    1320_at   94.3   A/absent          0.204022
# 
# [[2]]
#       ID_REF  VALUE   ABS_CALL DETECTION P-VALUE
# 1 10071_s_at 3473.6  P/present          0.000219
# 2    1053_at  643.2  P/present          0.000673
# 3     117_at  564.0 M/marginal          0.000322
# 4  1255_g_at    9.4   A/absent          0.602006
# 5    1294_at  845.6  P/present          0.000468
# 6    1320_at   94.3   A/absent          0.204022
# 
# [[3]]
#       ID_REF  VALUE   ABS_CALL DETECTION P-VALUE
# 1 10071_s_at 3473.6  P/present          0.000219
# 2    1053_at  643.2  P/present          0.000673
# 3     117_at  564.0 M/marginal          0.000322
# 4  1255_g_at    9.4   A/absent          0.602006
# 5    1294_at  845.6  P/present          0.000468
# 6    1320_at   94.3   A/absent          0.204022
```

Comment: If i need to search for all the rows, because i don't know how the data comes, if any entry is missing for any column. Then it need to be searched in other row as well

Comment: you could use `na.omit(data)[1, ]` instead of just `data[1, ]`. na.omit will filter out any row with any NA values, so if there is at least one row with all values, this should work

Comment: yeah ..that is an option. Thanks